# VisualVM and Self Time

Tags: java, performance, profiling, cpu, visualvm

I've been searching all over for a consistent and clear explanation of what 'self time' actually refers to in the VisualVM context and how does it differ to 'self time (cpu)'. Also does 'self time [%]' refer to self time or self time cpu.

There doesn't appear to be much documentation on this or at least I haven't found it. So any thoughts/input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

- `Self Time` is a *wall-clock time* spent in the method itself (**includes time waiting/sleeping**).
- `Self Time (CPU)` is a time *processor time*, so it does **NOT include** time spent **waiting, sleeping**, etc.
- Both columns do NOT include time spent in methods invoked from that method.
- Both `Self Time` and `Self Time (CPU)` in the sampler are *approximation* of actual data.
- `Self Time [%]` refers to one of the two selected `Self Time [(CPU)]` columns.

Comment: Adding to this even though it's an old question, in case it helps someone - it seems that 'self time [%]' will refer to whichever self time column you have sorted by. So if you sort by 'Self time (CPU)', the % will now be % of CPU time

Comment: Is it right to say that "self time" would be any time spent in sub-methods that are not instrumented to be profiled? So if method X calls method Y and Z, and method Z is not instrumented, any time spent in method Z will be the "self time" for method X?

Comment: @Marquez I just verified this by running the profiling twice: With and without excluding java.* packages; It influences the results exactly as you suspect: CPU time spent in classes that are not instrumented are counted towards the CPU self time of the invoking instrumented class;