# Visual VM: how to interpret Self Time vs Self Time (CPU)

Tags: java, cpu-usage, visualvm

I already read [VisualVM and Self Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626475/visualvm-and-self-time)

But I still don't get how to interpret. Here is my case :

```
Self Time : 500000ms
Self Time (CPU) : 72000ms
```

I understand that the method took 72s of CPU execution time (So real work without sub-method called).

Can I interpret that Threads have been blocked in this method for some reason during 500-72=428s ?

Which would mean I can begin to search concurrent access etc... ?

*Context* : Webapp under Tomcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I interpret that Threads have been blocked in this method for some reason during 500-72=428s ?

That is the most likely explanation.  It is also conceivable that the thread was descheduled by the thread sheduler to let other threads run.

> Which would mean I can begin to search concurrent access etc... ?

Synchronization (e.g. contention over locks or waiting for notifies) would be one possible possible explanation.  Another would be waiting for blocking I/O operations to complete.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove the suspicious method and see if my threads stop waiting. I'll be back for answer validation.