# java cpu profiling accuracy

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm, jvm-hotspot

I try to ensure the accuracy of some (free) java cpu profiling tools, e.g. sjk, visualvm.

Here is a sample program to do cpu-sensitive task:

`RandomStringUtils.java`:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomStringUtils {
    public String generate() {
        int leftLimit = 97; // letter 'a'
        int rightLimit = 122; // letter 'z'
        int targetStringLength = 10;
        Random random = new Random();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(targetStringLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < targetStringLength; i++) {
            int randomLimitedInt = leftLimit + (int)
                (random.nextFloat() * (rightLimit - leftLimit + 1));
            buffer.append((char) randomLimitedInt);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

`MainClass.java`:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MainClass {

    public String crypt(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String to encript cannot be null or zero length");
        }
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(str.getBytes());
            byte[] hash = md.digest();
            for (byte aHash : hash) {
                if ((0xff & aHash) < 0x10) {
                    hexString.append("0" + Integer.toHexString((0xFF & aHash)));
                } else {
                    hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aHash));
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long N = 1000 * 100;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            N = Long.parseLong(args[0], 10);
        }
        MainClass main = new MainClass();
        RandomStringUtils randomStringUtils = new RandomStringUtils();
        for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            main.crypt(randomStringUtils.generate());
        }
    }
}
```

For example, I use sjk to sample the cpu:

```
java -jar sjk-plus-0.11.jar stcap -p 3113 -f main -i 5ms -t 30s -o dump.std
java -jar sjk-plus-0.11.jar flame -f dump.std -o report.html
```

[image]

Here my question is, why the self time of `main()` is so large? And it only executes the loop. Doesn't the `encrypt()` and `generate()` occupy the whole cpu?

The visualvm shows the similar result.

Does sjk consider the self time and whole time? how to show them in command line report BTW?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626475/visualvm-and-self-time

Comment: It looks like you are including the initial class loading/verification/initialization time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very striking example of safepoint bias.

Below 3 flame graphs for slightly modified version of your code ([see on github](https://github.com/aragozin/proflab/blob/bench/cryptoprof/master/src/main/java/CryptoBench.java)).

**Using SJK sampling**
[image: Sampling with SJK]

SJK is using thread dump sampling aproach so result is skewed by [safepoint](https://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html) bias.

**Using Java Flight Recorder**
[image]

JFR is not affected by safepoint bias at sampling, but symbol map generated by JIT compiler is limited to safepoint checks by default. This has negative effect for reconstructing stack traces.

While results better than thread dump sampling, you can see anomalies. E.g. `Integer.toHexString` time is definitely exaggerated.

**Using Java Flight Recorder and additional JVM options**

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints
```

[image]

This tweaks to JVM start options picture becomes more accurate and detailed. `-XX:+DebugNonSafepoints` forces JIT compiler to generate detailed symbol maps.

Judging this example you could come to conclusion that Java Flight Recorder is universally better.

[Here](https://blog.ragozin.info/2019/03/lies-darn-lies-and-sampling-bias.html) you could find more elaborated explanation to this phenomena.