# Why is dequeue() taking so much processor time?

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm, jvisualvm, tomcat8.5

Visual VM shows FifoMessageDispatchChannel.dequeue() taking a lot of time. The Tomcat process is using around 100% of a processor core.

[image: dequeue() largest time consumer]

Comment: Your screenshot seems to say that `dequeue` uses zero processor time.

Comment: If you have problems with high CPU load, then you are suspecting wrong method. This thread is just waiting for messages in state `TIMED_WAITING` and consumes zero CPU time. To find real cause you need to sort records in VisualVM by CPU time.

Comment: Thanks Other Guy, Bedla

Comment: Other Guy or Bedla, can you say that in an answer with a reference that explains self time CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dequeue() is not taking much processor time as [that other guy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877501/why-is-dequeue-taking-so-much-processor-time#comment102180169_57877501). [This answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626475/visualvm-and-self-time#14654461) explains Self Time includes time spent doing things other than processing, such as waiting.

Self and Total Time (CPU) include time in the method using the processor and they are 0 for dequeue(). To find methods using the processor most, sort by Self Time (CPU), as [Bedla indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877501/why-is-dequeue-taking-so-much-processor-time#comment102180831_57877501).

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is that you are calling a consumer receive method with a very short wait but it is impossible to tell without more information.  The dispatch channel simply checks a queue for data and if none present will block for a given timeout waiting for a signal to wake and check again or time out and return.

Comment: Thanks very much, Tim. I'll see can I find something like that but I'm not sure what method to look for calls to. I don't know whether the method that's called is in Active MQ, Camel or something else.